# How to get mouse button state in Java?

Tags: java, api, mouse

Need to read mouse button state ("pressed" or "released") from simple java app. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) interface, or it's useful abstract implementation, [MouseAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html):

```
public class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private boolean pressed = false;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        this.pressed = true;
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        this.pressed = false;
    }

    public boolean isPressed() {
        return pressed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) is the class your are looking for